# Feedback for inherited code using Xor operator

Tags: excel, vba, xor

I'm quite new to VBA and have inherited a VBA code and the person that wrote this code protected the sheets with the below sub and function.

Is anyone able to decode the below? Seems like he is using special characters but this code is too advanced for my current understanding.

Any guidance or feedback would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub makeSafe(ws As Worksheet, safe As Boolean)

    If safe Then
        If Not ws.Name = "COMPLETED" Then
            ws.Columns("A:B").Locked = False
            ws.Columns("D").Locked = False
        End If
        ws.Protect XOREnc("½ ·Î½ ·", "nope")
    Else
        ws.Unprotect XOREnc("½ ·Î½ ·", "nope")
    End If

End Sub

Function XOREnc(theInput As String, theKey As String) As String

    Dim val1, val2 As Integer, out As String, temp As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(theInput)
        val1 = Asc(Mid(theInput, i, 1))
        val2 = Asc(Mid(theKey, i Mod Len(theKey) + 1, 1))
        If val1 Xor val2 < 32 Then
            temp = 255 - (val1 Xor val2)
        Else
            temp = val1 Xor val2
        End If
        out = out & Chr(temp)
     Next i
     XOREnc = out
End Function
```

Comment: The code is trying to hide a password, `-¯-_-¯-`. Evidently it is not doing a good job at hiding it, given that I just told you what it is.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I forgot to check if anyone had answered and actually got to the solution.